# Array object, cstring, read only pointer

Tags: visual-c++

How can I create array object with cstring in class? I also need to store names in read only pointer. 
any help would be really helpful..

Comment: `cstring`? Do you mean a `c` style string, `CString` from MFC, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I meant to ask char. I need to declare cstring (char myName[]) const pointer to store the name.                                                                                          class Leg{                                                                                                    
                Leg (char name)}; sth like this                                                                sorry for the unclear question. Thanks again..

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But a CStringArray might just be what you need.